# Is it risky or difficult to wet clean an image sensor?

Tags: sensor, cleaning, equipment-damage, maintenance

I've discovered spots on the image sensor of my DSLR camera that cannot be cleaned using a blower bulb, so I would like to know the risk of problems, such as further image deterioration or damage to the sensor or low-pass filter, associated with wet cleaning the image sensor.  Just how high (or low) is the risk?  Is this a difficult task to perform?

The products I expect to use are as follows:

- [Visible Dust Swabs for 1.5-1.6x Sensor - Green Series (12-Pack)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/435203-REG/Visible_Dust_2863171_Swabs_for_1_5_1_6x_Sensor.html)
- [Visible Dust VDust Plus Formula Solution](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/435207-REG/Visible_Dust_2902544_VDust_Plus_Formula_Solution.html)

In my research, I have also found the following products, for which there is a greater degree of trust because the manufacturer [guarantees against sensor damage](http://www.photosol.com/store/pc/viewContent.asp?idpage=12) when used properly:

- [Photographic Solutions Sensor Swab Type 2 (12-Pack)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/242758-REG/Photographic_Solutions_SS2BOX_Sensor_Swab_Type_2.html)
- [Photographic Solutions Eclipse Optic Lens Cleaning Solution](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/127525-REG/Photographic_Solutions_EC_Eclipse_Optic_Lens_Cleaning.html)

Additionally, the reviews are generally positive, so is it worth it?

My biggest concern at this point is further staining or residue from the cleaning process.  How likely is this going to affect image quality, and would it be worse compared to the dust or other contaminants?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do it regularly, I don't regard it as difficult. It's not that risky in the grand scheme of things but it's riskier than it used to be, especially with larger full frame sensors. Before the useless "self cleaning" function was implemented, the low pass filter assembly sat right on the sensor. Now there is an air gap to facilitate vibrating the LPF in order to dislodge dust. This airgap removes support for the glass LPF in the middle allowing it to bend and potentially break under pressure. See this photographers's cautionary tale:

http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/read.asp?forum=1032&message=30812646

So if you have a new camera with "self cleaning sensor" be **very** careful, esp. if it's full frame.

Comment: The camera is a [Pentax K-r](http://www.pentaximaging.com/slr/K-r_Black/), with an APS-C sensor.  The low-pass filter is fixed on the sensor; the self-cleaning mechanism simply uses the Shake Reduction system to shake the entire sensor.  It appears that when the shutter is open for sensor cleaning, the SR system tries to keep the sensor in place.

Comment: Self cleaning is rather useless, isn't it?

Comment: @DragonLord file that as a plus for sensor shake reduction over lens based shake reduction in that case! You should be fine as long as you use light pressure.

Comment: The self-cleaning only worked in a few isolated times with larger specks of dust.  A blower bulb was used to remove any other prominent dust.  However, many other spots could not be removed with the blower bulb.

Comment: Actually. The self-cleaning system works well, only it cleans small particles that have very little impact on IQ. When the particles are big and more important to remove it is useless. At least progress was made!

Comment: Sensor shake for this is handy, but not perfect. With my K-5s, I will do the menu based option on lens change, otherwise I just have it on startup. It's not 100%, but it really cuts down the overall volume of dust.

Comment: JoanneC: the K-5 and K-7 have an ultrasonic vibrating low-pass filter for self-cleaning, unlike the K-r and other entry-level models.

Comment: I'll buy the Photographic Solutions cleaning products.  It seems that reports of sensor damage are caused by improper cleaning tools or procedures; failures resulting from proper use of the correct products are rare, so I'll take a shot at it.

Comment: I took a leap of faith and went ahead with wet cleaning.  After three Sensor Swabs, some Eclipse, and my blower bulb, the sensor was essentially clean without any damage.  Thanks for your help, @MattGrum and others!

Comment: I find self-cleaning most useful if set to run automatically each time the camera is powered on/off. It does fairly well with smaller dust that has not had time to get wet/moist and stick to the sensor. Once dust on the sensor is exposed to humid air, it is much harder to remove with anything other than wet cleaning.

Answer (score 4):

It's both risky and difficult.

Sensor cleaning has come a long way from the DIY solutions used many years ago, but it's still not fool proof. Most the sites that sell such products have ample enough warnings which should be a clear indication of the risks involved.

A licensed camera repair facility can easily clean the sensor for you.

Or you could consider waiting till the problem becomes much more noticeable, and use image processing (clone/healing brushes) to mask out the problem until then.

Comment: Who, exactly, *licenses* a camera repair facility?

Comment: President Obama.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that risky (apart from as previously mentioned the self cleaning sensors).

However I find it difficult, because it's hard to remove all of the residue from even dedicated cleaners.  If you need to do this (and some things like pollen even the best sensor brush will not remove) then just be careful and apply a VERY tiny amount of fluid to clean with (a drop or two).  Look when you are done if there is any kind of sheen across the sensor, you can try sample shots of something very flat in color across the whole frame (out of focus white paper with flat lighting) to make sure any residue left is not affecting the image.

I also like the Visible Dust sensor cleaning pads, they are very wide and let you do a wet clean with just a pass or two.  They have a sensor cleaning solution that seems to work just fine but you may be able to find cheaper cleaning solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I say: DON'T TOUCH THAT OLP filter! You can clean it a hundred times and don't have any worries, and the 101th time you accidently pick up a piece of grid, and you scratch your filter! That is what happened to me! A 1000€ camera, and a 500€ to fix it! Send it back to the manufacturer! Dust? Blow it off, but leave those swabs and Eclipse alone! (I had oil spots on the sensor, coming from the mirror mechanism.)