# How to clean spit off my camera sensor?

Tags: sensor, cleaning

A short while ago, I [foolishly] attempted to clean some specs of dust from the sensor of my camera by blowing on it.  While this was successful in removing the dust, I inadvertently spat on the sensor...  I bought a rocket blower and some sensor swabs from my local shop and used these on the sensor again, but they have not been successful in removing the specs/deposits of spit.  Is there any other type of DIY cleaning I can perform to remove these residues, or do I need to get this looked at by a professional?

Comment: I wouldn't say that spit is a special circumstance. I would try the regular methods of wet cleaning the sensor. See: [What is the best way to clean the sensor on a digital SLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-the-sensor-on-a-digital-slr) and [Is it risky or difficult to wet clean an image sensor?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/is-it-risky-or-difficult-to-wet-clean-an-image-sensor)

Comment: I guess it's not much of a special case, but I asked because I tried the methods described in the other answer (using moistened sensor swabs) and it did not remove the marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along with the sensor swabs you need some wet cleaner specifically designed for cleaning the sensor, or more specifically the *Infrared/Low pass filter* mounted in front of the actual sensor. Use only one or two drops on each swab and swipe once in each direction using opposite sides of the tip of the swab for each pass. Repeat with a clean swab until all of the dried spittle is removed. Don't be afraid to apply gentle pressure as you move the swab across the filter/sensor. Part of the design of the swabs is a flexible handle that makes it hard to put too much pressure on the filter. It takes a few tries to get the knack for using the swabs to remove everything. My initial difficulty was with leaving small specks of dust in the corners of the sensor.